# How to use sed regex to replace to words related to each other and one character between them

Tags: sed, regular-expression

How to use sed regex to replace to words related to each other and one character between them with out change the character and the two words as group 
like that

```
ahmed#mohamed 
ahmed$mohamed
ahmed7mohamed
```

I didn't want to replace `ahmed` only and then replace `mohamed` only

I used

```
sed -i 's/ahmed.mohamed/mohamed.ahmed/g'
```

but make all like this I want to keep the character between them.

```
mohamed.ahmed
mohamed.ahmed
mohamed.ahmed
```

Comment: Thanks for showing us the result that you *got* from the command that you tried, but you should also show the result that you ***want**.*  Your *explanation* of the result you wanted is pretty good, but not entirely clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. You need to use capturing parentheses:

```
sed -E -i 's/ahmed(.)mohamed/mohamed\1ahmed/g'
```

The `\1` is replaced with the text of the *first* set of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You want to swap the two strings `ahmed` and `mohamed` that are separated by some character.

The issue in your expression,

```
s/ahmed.mohamed/mohamed.ahmed/
```

is that the character in-between the words is always replaced by a dot.  The solution is to capture the character and replace it with itself.

This is one way of doing so with `sed`, which also uses the same capturing mechanism to avoid typing in the two strings again for the replacement:

```
sed 's/\(ahmed\)\(.\)\(mohamed\)/\3\2\1/'
```

or,

```
sed -E 's/(ahmed)(.)(mohamed)/\3\2\1/'
```

Testing on the given data:

```
$ sed -E 's/(ahmed)(.)(mohamed)/\3\2\1/' <file
mohamed#ahmed
mohamed$ahmed
mohamed7ahmed
```